# Delete my Key column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I create a table in mySQL and now my table is like this:
[image]

Now, i want to delete the "type","null","Key","Default", and "Extra" columns and add my ideal named columns.

But it has error with this statement:

```
mysql> alter table mytable drop column Extra
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'Extra'; check that column/Key Exists
mysql>
```

Comment: Your table columns are Fname, Lname, age, and phone!!! what you're seing is the properties of your columns :D

Comment: @DanyY How can see mytable without mytable metadatas?

Comment: select * from mytable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those are not columns you can modify, they are metadata propertes of each user column the database needs to work, your columns you can modify are `Fname`, `Lname`, `age` and `phone`.

The console output confusingly calls them `Fields` but they are your user columns for that table you have called `mytable`. What you are seeing and thinking are columns are metadata properties of the fields. Each field has a `type`, `is nullable`, `is a key`, has an optional `default` value, and some `extra` data. These are things the database needs to operate.

#### From the MySQL Reference Manual

> If you want to find out about the **structure of a table**, the DESCRIBE
>   statement is useful; it displays information about each of a table's
>   columns:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE pet;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| owner   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| species | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sex     | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| birth   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| death   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

> **Field** indicates the column name, **Type** is the data type for the column,
>   **NULL** indicates whether the column can contain NULL values, **Key**
>   indicates whether the column is indexed, and **Default** specifies the
>   column's default value. **Extra** displays special information about
>   columns: If a column was created with the AUTO_INCREMENT option, the
>   value will be auto_increment rather than empty.

If you want to see the **DATA** in your table then use `Select` instead of `Describe`; see the above explanation of what `Describe` actually does.

Comment: But, Fname Lname age and phone are my fileds!

Comment: I was accustomed to say that the vertical columns columns

Comment: Can i see my table without Additional information?

Comment: Like see just my Columns!

Comment: Define what you think you mean to accomplish with ***see my table***; that statement doesn't actually mean anything since `DESCRIBE` shows you the *structure of your table*, it **IS** showing your columns and what kind of columns they are; as it is, you are displaying a lack of understanding that I don't think any explanation will overcome.

Answer (score 1):

@Sajjad your fields ARE your columns

Your table is `mytable(Fname, Lname,age,phone)`

to see it more clearly try `select * from mytable`

`describe` givesyou each column and its properties

Comment: I was accustomed to say that the vertical columns columns

Comment: man you should read about the basics of SQL. * lets you select all the columns of a table, it's like doing `select Fname, Lname,age,phone from mytable`

Comment: select * from mytable output was Empty set!

Comment: forget about the metadata, `select * from mytable` is empty because you have no records